# mysql_real_escape_string and Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

I understand I need to connect to the db in order for mysql_real_escape_string to work, but not quite sure how.

I use this function to insert rows in tables.

```
function insert_db($conn, $table_name, $array){

    //$array = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string' , $db ); //ERROR! 

    # Create the SQL Query
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `'.$table_name.'` '.
             '( `'.implode( '` , `' , array_keys( $array ) ).'` ) '.
             'VALUES '.
             '( "'.implode( '" , "' , $array ).'" )';

    $result = $conn->query($query);             
    if (!$result){ trigger_error("mysql error: ".mysql_errno($result) . ": " . mysql_error($result));  }
}
```

It takes an array like this for example:

```
$db["to"] = $to;
$db["from"] = $username; 
$db["message"] = $message;
$db["time"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+0 minutes"));

insert_db($conn, "inbox", $db)
```

where the array keys represent columns in a table.

But I get this error:

```
2011-02-01 22:21:29 : mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Somebody asked where `$conn` came from:

```
$conn = db_connect();

if( ! function_exists('db_connect')){

    function db_connect() {
    $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    if (!$result) {
    die(msg(0,"Could not connect to database server"));
    } else {
    return $result;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `$conn` in your code coming from? It looks like it's not a connection (created by `mysql_connect`). You can't send queries (or escape strings or anything else) to the database server without first opening a connection to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your connection is using mysqli (**i**) so you cant use a mysql* function, you want  mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: close, but `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given `

Comment: @ganjan, no, he's not calling mysqli_real_escape_string, he's trying to use mysql_real_escape_string() which is the problem

Comment: ganjan asked the question so I know, but when I just change `mysql_real_escape_string() ` to `mysqli_real_escape_string`, I still get an error (mentioned above).

Comment: @ganjan they are not identical, you cant just swap, *i* has 2 parameters. i never said replace one with other without taking the differences in to account.

Comment: @ganjan: As always, your salvation is found in the documentation: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string